# Where bind9 slave server stores transfered zone file?

Tags: configuration, dns, bind

Configured bind9 simple master-slave tandem for serving domain in local network.
Transfer of zone to client succeeds but I find no transfered zone file on slave server.

Configuration at master:

```
zone "lab." {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/db.lab";
  allow-transfer { 192.168.1.5; };
};
```

Configuration at slave:

```
zone "lab." {
  type slave;
  masters { 192.168.1.2; };
  file "/etc/bind/zones/db.lab";
};
```

Zone transfer suceeds, systemd log at master:

```
... named[1345] client 192.168.1.5#4167 (lab): transfer of 'lab/IN': AXFR started (serial 5)
... named[1345] client 192.168.1.5#4167 (lab): transfer of 'lab/IN': AXFR ended
```

And slave server serves zone when I shutdown master server.
However, no file appeared in specified path at slave server.

**May be it's stored in memory? Is it expected behaviour?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the delay of answer mate, strange that nobody have already answered to that question of yours. I guess you already figured it out but just in case...

So, you shouldn't decide where to put the file yourself. As said in [ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto#Secondary_Master_Server_configuration), Apparmor doesn't allow to place the files where ever you want.

Just put on your slave named.conf.local something like: `file "db.example.com";`  in place of `file "/etc/bind/zones/db.lab";` and you will see some files appearing in `/var/cache/bind/`.

[EDIT]

Reason for the existence of AppArmor -

> A short guide to get you started on AppArmor
>
> AppArmor is a linux security module that allows for path based mandatory >access control. It’s easy to learn and very effective at both preventing >and containing exploits. I suggest you make use of it.

available [here](http://www.insanitybit.com/2012/05/29/apparmor-how-to/)

Comment: You mean, because of AppArmor's behaviour absolute paths doesn't work? Only relative?

Comment: no, I mean that because of rules of AppArmor (which defines specific settings which is considered as more secure for each app), the only path which is authorized for bind is this one. If you need another one then you need to specify it in AppArmor and possibily in bind. I've edited my answer to give you a better overview of what's the reason of existence of AppArmor.